# Unity crash при отладке в Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, unity3d, отладка

Столкнулся с багом непонятной природы. Воспроизводится на Юнити 2021.3.25 и 2022.3.4.
Ставлю брейкпоинт на условной строке кода, подключаю к Юнити, инициирую выполнение кода из редактора (замечание: не из плей-мода, а именно из редактора). Одновременно с попаданием в брейкпоинт происходит краш Юнити, при этом останов всё-таки срабатывает, появляется жёлтая стрелка в нужной строке в студии, но затем из-за краша процесса происходит отключение отладки.
Кто сталкивался, как побеждать?

Comment: Ставлю точки останова на той же версии студии и Unity, не крашится. В описании вопроса не содержится причины проблемы. Обновите винду, дрова, .NET через центр обновлений винды. Краш-логи можно посмотреть в журналах Windows, возможно там есть указатель на причину.

Comment: Действительно, в журнале событий ошибка дотнета 1023. Насколько я нашёл информацию, я такой не один, эта проблема возникает у некоторых людей после обновления 22 студии до версии 17.6.Х.
Содержимое ошибки:
"Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: ServiceHub.IndexingService.exe
Path: F:\Programms\Visual Studio 2022\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.Dotnet.x64\ServiceHub.IndexingService.exe
Message: Failed to read environment variable [DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS], HRESULT: 0x800700CB".